# Is there a way to view Gnome Software's ODRS reviews on the web?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I was looking at user reviews and ratings of software in the Gnome Software application on my Fedora system, and wondered where the user reviews came from. A bit of digging and I found the [Open Desktop Ratings System](https://odrs.gnome.org/), which apparently is also used by Ubuntu.

But the ratings don't appear on the website views of Flathub or the Snap store, or any other website I can find, so if I'm researching software, I have to be on my Fedora system to see this set of ratings. (Yes, I can find other user reviews. I'm curious about this collection.)

Is there a website that shows the ODRS reviews/ratings somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

There's [odrs-browser](https://paroj.github.io/odrs-browser/) but it uses old scraped data. That's because ODRS currently can't be consumed by browser clients due to CORS policies.